# java: cannot find symbol in gnw Predictions.java

Tags: java

I am trying to compile https://github.com/tschaffter/gnw. I am getting the error:

```
Error:(1016, 44) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class PredictionTab
  location: class ch.epfl.lis.gnwgui.Predictions
```

However, PredictionTab is defined in PredictionsPanel.java which is imported at the top of Predictions.java with:

```
import ch.epfl.lis.gnwgui.windows.PredictionsPanel;
```

Comment: [I don't see PredictionTab imported anywhere in the source code and I don't see a PredictionTab.java either](https://github.com/tschaffter/gnw/blob/master/src/ch/epfl/lis/gnwgui/Predictions.java)

Comment: PredictionTab is defined in PredictionsPanel.java

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using  `PredictionTab` but you're importing `PredictionsPanel`. I would just `import ch.epfl.lis.gnwgui.windows.*` to make sure it worked initially.

Also make sure you're adding the ch.epfl.lis.gnwgui.windows.PredictionsPanel class to your classpath. Whatever jar it exsists in, you either have to 1) compile with that or 2) export it to your $PATH in something like your bach_profile.

javac -cp .:path/to/the/jar/file.jar Whatever.java
java -cp .:path/to/the/jar/file.jar Whatever
That or you can use a tool like Gradle, Ant, or Maven to include dependencies on something like a pom.xml.

Comment: Changing the import to ch.epfl.lis.gnwgui.windows.* didn't help. I added the entire src folder to the class path and that didn't help either. Could it have something to do with PredictionTab being an inner class to PredictionsPanel?